# Phrase for "changing street side"?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation, german

Imagine you're walking on a pedestrian path, you see a shady person coming towards you and you cross the street to continue walking on the other side.
In German, there's a short and easily comprehensible phrase for this:

> die Straßenseite wechseln

but I can't think of an English equivalent - "change street side" brought no google results and doesn't sound right.

Comment: I don't see the shortcomings of "cross the street," an expression you used in this question. What's the short and easily comprehensible German phrase?

Comment: If I am walking home and there is a dirty guy talking to himself and cursing a lot, I _cross the street._ That's as short as you are going to get.

Comment: In British English "cross the *road*" would be common

Comment: @ChrisH That would depend on whether you were walking on a street or a road:-)

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the German phrase.

Comment: Lengthier than simply “cross the street” is “cross to the other side of the street” which is probably what I’d say if I was relaying a story like that.

Comment: Germans probably consider *farfegnugen* and *Schadenfreude* to be "short and eaily comprehensible".

Comment: I dont know, "Cross the street" just didnt sound like it would transmit the thought of going from one side to the other - in german i say "Straßenseite wechseln" which literally means "Changing side of the Street", when i think of someone crossing the road, i think of someone who just wants to get from A to B, not someone who is walking, then changing sides, and then continuing to walk. It sounds very weird when i write it like that i have to say...

Answer (score 1):

If trying to avoid an old adversary or time wasting acquaintance I may find I

> "switch sides of the street" or "change sides of the street"

for an example see #5 & #8 [Ways to Prevent and Defend Yourself Against a Street Assault](https://www.waterandrockstudio.com/1262-2/)

or more simply (informally)

> "cross sides"

(and continue in the same direction) to avoid them.

I tried looking for a suitable definition and cant find "cross sides" but in common parlance it describes the defensive movement a pedestrian should consider making when approaching a bend in an unpaved vehicular area (lane road or street) to avoid oncoming traffic.

As commented by  – @marcellothearcane

A very common British term understood by most people would be **'cross the road'**

> You see a shady person coming towards you and you **"cross the road"**
>   to continue walking on the other side.

Comment: To include common British usage, you could add 'cross the road'